Flutter doctor --> Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 36.0.0-rc1)
I’m trying to run Flutter app using Android Studio from scratch. I’m currently using the latest version, 'Ladybug,' and I’ve also tried installing different Java versions. And also i correctly set the path variables in each time. However, I’m unable to identify the exact issue causing the problem.
when i run the flutter app the console shows as follow
Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone64 x86 64 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
Error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 255

When trigger "flutter doctor -v "
C:\flutter\src\flutter\bin>flutter doctor -v
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.27.0, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.26100.2605], locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 3.27.0 on channel stable at C:\flutter\src\flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 8495dee1fd (8 days ago), 2024-12-10 14:23:39 -0800
    • Engine revision 83bacfc525
    • Dart version 3.6.0
    • DevTools version 2.40.2

[√] Windows Version (Installed version of Windows is version 10 or higher)

[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 36.0.0-rc1)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\Gayashan Pathirana\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
    • Platform android-31, build-tools 36.0.0-rc1
    • Java binary at: <C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17>\bin\java
    X Cannot execute <C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17>\bin\java to determine the version

[√] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

[√] Visual Studio - develop Windows apps (Visual Studio Community 2022 17.11.3)
    • Visual Studio at C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community
    • Visual Studio Community 2022 version 17.11.35303.130
    • Windows 10 SDK version 10.0.22621.0

[√] Android Studio (version 2024.2)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 21.0.3+-12282718-b509.11)

[√] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2022.3)
    • IntelliJ at C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2022.3.2
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart

[√] VS Code (version 1.96.0)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\Gayashan Pathirana\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.102.0

[√] Connected device (4 available)
    • RMX2180 (mobile)  • adb-6PMFVGOFA6I74TC6-WDe0Xb._adb-tls-connect._tcp • android-arm64  • Android 11 (API 30)
    • Windows (desktop) • windows                                           • windows-x64    • Microsoft Windows
      [Version 10.0.26100.2605]
    • Chrome (web)      • chrome                                            • web-javascript • Google Chrome
      131.0.6778.140
    • Edge (web)        • edge                                              • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge
      131.0.2903.99

[√] Network resources
    • All expected network resources are available.

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.


Try flutter config --list - is jdk-dir set? If so, you should probably unset it so that Flutter will use the "the JDK bundled with the latest installation of Android Studio". Use flutter config --help for more options

thank you. it's makes me to the right direction.

I suspect that you properly set the PATH as C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17\bin
However, still in your environment variables,
You have to set your JAVA_HOME as C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17 not C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17\bin
Perform invalidate caches if necessary by File > Invalidate Caches... in Android Studio.
Then rebuild your app again, or retry flutter doctor -v
I hope it helps!
